# How to insert normal-font text inside verbatim?

Tags: fonts, verbatim, code

In the ISO C++ standard papers, blocks of code are displayed in a `verbatim`-like environment, but the comments inside the code are in normal font. For example:

[image: Sample code with comments]

The comments "7.3.5, CommonReference:" etc. are in normal font, and the links work properly. How is this implemented?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I recall correctly you may choose a different font for comments when working with packages like `listings`.

Comment: Please edit your posting to provide an example of a C++ code block with associated comments. That'll make it much easier to provide specific and usable solutions.

Comment: Please also indicate which dialect of C++ you employ. I.e., is it ISO, Visual, GNU, ANSI, or 11?

Comment: OK. BTW, I thought ISO is implied by writing "C++ standard". But clarity is good :-)

Comment: OK, instead of a screenshot of formatted code, please post the code itself.

Comment: I asked this question simply because I do not know the original code in order to render those formatted screenshots :( Sorry I can't find them

Comment: You could use `listings` and something like `\lstset{language=C++,basicstyle=\ttfamily,commentstyle=\normalfont\itshape}`: `\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C++,basicstyle=\ttfamily,commentstyle=\normalfont\itshape}


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
// 7.5.3, Rome
template <class T, class U>
concept bool egg=hatch
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}`

Comment: Thank you! The only unsatisfactory thing is that the code is too much spaced.. Does there exist a way to adjust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `listings`. However, escaping to LaTeX will not preserve the current style (comment, in your case) so I provide a suitable command for the job.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\lstset{
  language=C++,
  columns=fullflexible,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\mycommentstyle,
  escapechar=\$,
}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor=blue,
}

\newcommand{\mycommentstyle}{\normalfont\itshape}
\newcommand{\commentref}[1]{{\mycommentstyle\ref{#1}}}


\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{7} % to emulate your numbering
\setcounter{section}{3}
\setcounter{subsection}{4}

\subsection{Common reference}\label{cr}

This will be pointed to by the link.

\begin{lstlisting}
// $\commentref{cr}$, CommonReference:
template <class T, class U>
concept bool CommonReference = see below;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in `lstlisting` environment, as following

```latex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[UTF8, english]{article}

\usepackage{listings, xcolor}
\lstset{
tabsize = 4, %% set tab space width
showstringspaces = false, %% prevent space marking in strings, string is defined as the text that is generally printed directly to the console
numbers = left, %% Displays line numbers on the left
keywordstyle = \color{blue}, %% set keyword color
stringstyle = \color{red}, %% set string color
rulecolor = \color{black}, %% set frame color to avoid being affected by text color
basicstyle = \small \ttfamily , %% set listing font and size
breaklines = true, %% enable line breaking
numberstyle = \tiny,
commentstyle = \rmfamily,
}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor = blue, anchorcolor = blue, citecolor = green]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language = C++, frame = trBL, firstnumber = last, escapeinside = {(*@}{@*)}]
#include <iostream>
// here is the comment and clickable (*@\href{https://ctan.org/pkg/listings}{link}@*) in roman font family
int main() 
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

You would get

[image: comment and link]

Comment: Well, what I actually want: 1) code in monospace 2) comment in normal font 3) links in comment work

Comment: @L.F. I don't think anyone can give you links in the midst of verbatim text.  Are you sure you need `verbatim` style?

Comment: @L.F. I have updated the code to `lstlisting` environment which works, except for one small point, the link text, since escaped from the `lstlisting` environment, is not in normal font, but still clickable. I would be grateful if anyone could help me fix this small little problem.